# Using a variable value in <meta http-equiv="refresh" content=" url="/>?

Tags: php, variables, redirect, header, meta

Alright, in my PHP file I need the program to make a redirect from the middle of a big if-loop.
I can successfully use the command to redirect to another page when I manually set the seconds, like:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url='www.google.com'"/>';
```

However, in the background I run a SQL-query, from where I get the refresh "rate". That value I have passed into a variable, and I want to use the variable value like this:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="'.$refreshvalue.'; url='www.google.com'"/>';
```

I don't know where is the problem. In my program, everything works out as intended when I set the value manually, but when I try to get the value from the variable, the program simply does not execute the redirect.

The query gives me the correct value, and I can pass it to variable. But there's something wrong in the syntax, I assume. I've tried couple of other ways.

Also, if you have a simple alternative to using 'meta' or php function header(), I'm more than interested to hear about it.

Is my syntax wrong, or what's up here?

Comment: what you are trying to achieve ? seems that you are trying to force PHP to act as a client-side which will may cause a troubles for you

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `header()` function in PHP? You do realise PHP compiles and executes first then displays a HTML copy of itself. Using `header()` and `exit()` will have a different effect than setting the meta tags within a header. Since the header tags are only executed when the page is displayed, not executed

Comment: @hassan The basic idea is that when another sql query has returned more than X-amount of rows, the site redirects to another site. What I'm achieving here, is that the end-user wants to be able to modify the time between redirects.

Comment: what's the output of evaluating this `echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="'.$refreshvalue.'; url='www.google.com'"/>';` ?

Comment: @WillParky93 Alright, I am basicly experimenting with the ideas here. I tried to use php header before this, but I could not use the variable value there either.

Comment: @hassan After X-seconds have passed, the site should redirect to google. $refreshvalue contains an integer in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure, `$refreshvalue` contains an valid integer value and all quotes are correctly escaped? It should look something like this

```
$refreshvalue = 2;
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="' . $refreshvalue . '; url=\'http://www.google.com\'"/>';
```

Comment: It should, unless I'm doing something stupid here.
$sql = "SELECT secamount FROM seconds WHERE typeid=1";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$refreshvalue = $result;

When I run the query in PHPmyAdmin, I get a single integer as a result.

Comment: var_dump($refreshvalue); to ensure the value is what you expect.

Comment: `mysli::query` returns an `mysqli_result` object. You have to fetch the first row and from that the column `secamount`

Comment: `$refreshvalue = $result->fetch_array()['secamount']`

Comment: Awesome, thank you Philipp and Nic. Now that I processed the query value correctly, it works!

Answer (score 0):

You have a quoting problem.  Change it to this:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"" . $refreshvalue . "; url=http://www.google.com/\">";
```

As presented in your question, you are closing your string just before www.google.com with the '
Note also the addition of http:// in front.